# Route traffic from ASA to different firewall default gateway

Tags: networking, firewall, routing

I should probably start by explaining the topography, we have two different internet connection with separate firewalls.One is an asa and one is a meraki, the default gateway for all the servers behind the firewalls is the ASA (10.100.200.1). The problem I am having is that we have a site to site on the meraki (10.100.200.2) and the traffic destined for the subnet(192.168.100.0) on the other side of the site to site can't find its way because it is trying to go through the asa's default gateway(10.100.200.1). If I set a static route on the server that is trying to send traffic to the subnet(192.168.100.0) to use the meraki's default gateway(10.100.200.2) it works. How do a set a static route on the asa so that any traffic that comes through the meraki uses the meraki's default gateway to get out?

Comment: If it is a Site-to-Site why can't you set a static route on the ASA? Something like: `route inside 192.168.100.0 255.255.255.0 10.100.200.2`? Bear in mind I made up the interface and networks based on common standards. Tweak for your network as needed.